# Gradle fails to execute ant task

Tags: java, gradle, ant, ivy

I am trying to run `ant` task from gradle file

In my **build.gradle** I imported the `ant` file

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

In my **build.xml** I having two simple tasks

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="simpleAntTask">
        <echo>I am a ant task</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="ivyTask">
        <ivy:buildnumber
            organisation="daniel"
            module="hello"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

When `Gradle` runs the task `simpleAntTask` everything goes as expected and it's prints ok :

```
2:14:31: Executing external task 'simpleAntTask'...
:simpleAntTask
[ant:echo] I am a ant task

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.565 secs
2:14:32: External task execution finished 'simpleAntTask'.
```

---

But when I am running the `ant` task that uses the `ivy` task Gradle throws errors :

```
:ivyTask FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ivyTask'.
> Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:buildnumber
  Cause: The name is undefined.
  Action: Check the spelling.
  Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
  Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
  No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

  This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
  Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
          -ANT_HOME/lib
          -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs
```

I searched for a long time in the internet for a solution but couldn't find anything,
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Does it work when you run the target directly with Ant? I'm guessing it won't. It looks like you haven't defined the Ivy tasks anywhere in your build. Simply setting the `ivy:` XML namespace isn't enough.

Comment: @CAustin actually it works , of course i also have ivysettings